# Issue connecting to some servers using libssh2

Tags: c++, linux, ssh

I have an issue in `Libssh2 - 1.7.0` and/or `OpenSSL 1.1.0.`

When connecting through SSH using the compiled API to an old Linux box, everything is as expected.

When trying to connect to a more recent distribution, the connection fails with error:

> Failure establishing SSH session: -8.

I read that this error is related to the `curl/libcurl` version on the Linux machines, but I can't upgrade or download the curl version on them.

The same problem is raised with AIX recent versions.

Any help?

Comment: There's many unclean details here. As a start: what protocol do you want to use: ssh/scp/sftp/ftps/https/other?

Comment: Some details about the client? Eg: AIX, home-made program using libssh2.

Comment: I use AIX v. 7.1.0.0

Comment: libssh2 v.1.7.0

Comment: AIX has SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0

Comment: For a test, I've compiled `OpenSSL 1.0.2h` and `libssh2 1.7.0` then tested `/usr/local/src/libssh2-1.7.0/example/ssh2` to connect OpenSSH-7.x on AIX/linux. It did work.

Comment: I tried ssl v 1.0.2d for windows. Not success

Comment: I tried ssl v.1.0.2h too. And not successfully . It's my log :

Comment: File -  session.c
 Function -  session_startup
 Data - Unable to exchange encryption keys
 rc: -8